# Remove character from a value in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i am trying to remove all the character beside the last 4 from all the values in a numpy array.
I'd normally use [-4:] but if i use that on the arra i only obtain the last 4 values in the array.

`andatum = andatum[-4:] print(andatum)`

'15.11.1999'
'15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999'
'15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999'
'15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999'
'15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999'
'15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999']

runfile('O:/GIS/GEP/Risikomanagement/Flussvermessung/ALD/Analyses/ReadFilesToRawData.py', wdir='O:/GIS/GEP/Risikomanagement/Flussvermessung/ALD/Analyses')
['15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999' '15.11.1999']

What i am trying to do is to obtain the same array but only with the last 4 digits (the year).
Any idea how i could do that?

Thank you,

Davide

I would like to remove all the characters beside the last 4 (the year) but using [-4:] i get the last 4 entries of my numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`andatum[i]` will reference items in the array. To reference individual characters of these items, you need to use multiple brackets like this `andatum[i][x]`

To get array of only last 4 characters you need to go over each item of the array like this:

```
for i in range(len(andatum)):
    andatum[i] = andatum[i][:-4]
```

Or to keep things more tidy and also faster, this oneliner should also do the work:

`andatum = [x[:-4] for x in andatum]`

Comment: A list comprehension isn't usually significantly faster than a regular loop. Also, the list comprehension changes `andatum` to a _`list`_ (it used to be a `np.array`)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a 1d array of strings:

```
In [28]: arr = np.array(['15.11.1999']*6)    
In [29]: arr
Out[29]: 
array(['15.11.1999', '15.11.1999', '15.11.1999', '15.11.1999',
       '15.11.1999', '15.11.1999'], dtype='<U10')
```

`numpy` is better for numbers than strings.  This array is little better than a list of strings.  But for convenience, `numpy` has a set of functions that apply string methods to the elements of an array.

```
In [30]: np.char.split(arr, sep='.')
Out[30]: 
array([list(['15', '11', '1999']), list(['15', '11', '1999']),
       list(['15', '11', '1999']), list(['15', '11', '1999']),
       list(['15', '11', '1999']), list(['15', '11', '1999'])],
      dtype=object)
```

We can convert this to a 2d array of strings with `stack` (or `vstack`):

```
In [31]: np.stack(_)
Out[31]: 
array([['15', '11', '1999'],
       ['15', '11', '1999'],
       ['15', '11', '1999'],
       ['15', '11', '1999'],
       ['15', '11', '1999'],
       ['15', '11', '1999']], dtype='<U4')
```

And select a column:

```
In [32]: np.stack(_)[:,2]
Out[32]: array(['1999', '1999', '1999', '1999', '1999', '1999'], dtype='<U4')
```

`np.char` does not have a function to index the strings.  For that we have to stick with a list comprehension

```
In [33]: [i[-4:] for i in arr]
Out[33]: ['1999', '1999', '1999', '1999', '1999', '1999']
```

That kind of iteration is faster with lists.

Comment: Thank you very much. I must say i am a bit confused about the data types of my array (asnd also between array and lists). It looks like a date and i'd like to extract the year. I couldnt transform it in a number so far. even if i extract the last four digits it still stays like '1999' (between quotation). How can i change that?